# Does ZF-independency of an axiom implicate non-constructivity?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Let's take the axiom of choice - when we add it to ZF, we get a theory that can be used to obtain non-constructive results. Is this the case for all axioms that are independent of ZF? (e.g. continuum hypothesis?)

Comment: What is a "non-constructive result"?

Comment: [This](https://mathoverflow.net/q/297738) question concerns a sense in which $\mathsf{ZF}$ is constructive. Your question is whether it's a _maximal_ theory with this property (or some other that question doesn't address), i.e. any undecidable axiom we could add to it drops this property. I'm not sure whether @RodrigoFreire's answer there, in saying it's the "best possible" result of this kind, answers you in the affirmative or means $\mathsf{ZF}$ is not in general "even more conservative" than that, but I expect the correct reading is the latter.